# open('file_path').read() - save contents back to file

Tags: python, django, file

I need to upload a file to the server using urllib2. Since I cannot use any external libraries (like `requests` and others) because I am using OpenOffice python, I needed a simple way to post file data.

So I came with:

```
post_url = "http://localhost:8000/admin/oo_file_uploader?user_id=%s&file_id=%s" % (user_id, file_id)
file_path = doc.Location.replace('file://', '')
data = urllib.urlencode({"file": open(file_path).read()})
urllib2.urlopen(post_url, data)
```

which posts something to the server.

I wonder if it is possible to save posted contents back to the file using python/django?

Answer (score 0):

This expands somewhat on @zero323's answer.  You will want to make sure that you implement some sort of security to prevent random files being uploaded by unauthorized users, which is what the `@file_upload_security` decorator is implied to handle.

```
@file_upload_security
def oo_file_uploader(user_id=None, file_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Exception handling skipped if get() fails.
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        save_to_file = MyFiles.objects.get(id=file_id)

        # You will probably want to ensure 'file' is in post data.
        file_contents = save_to_file.parse_post_to_content(request.POST['file'])

        with open(save_to_file.path_to_file, 'w') as fw:
            fw.write(file_contents)
```